# Android how to use different layouts for each listview item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

In my application I can only use the same layout for each listview item in each row. This is not what I want for my application and I would like to have a different layout for each of the listview items.

As an example of what I would like to achieve please see the screenshot below.

[image: different layout each listview items]

Comment: create two different rows in xml. In your custom adapter class use view holder to store the inflated objects, select the rows as per your need in the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via android Listview BaseAdapter. In BaseAdapter getView method, you can added code like this.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(item1 or your condition)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.from_right_row.xml, parent, false);
        }else if(item2 or your condition) {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.from_left_row.xml, parent, false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good way to inflate views. Avoid passing null as the parent view.